# Subquery with groupby and having

Tags: sql-server

Hey guys I am a little stumped on this one. Here is the statement. I am looking for patients who have had more then 3 visits in the past 6 months. I though this would give me the easier awnser.

```
SELECT od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_ARPTYPE, 
       od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_NAME, 
       od_ar_demographics.MR_NUMBER, 
       OD_IP1.IP1ADMIT_DATE, 
       OD_IP1.IP1DISC_DATE, 
       od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_TYPE
FROM            od_ar_demographics INNER JOIN
                         OD_IP1 ON od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_NUMBER = OD_IP1.IP0NUMBER
where         Mr_number in (select MR_number from (SELECT MR_number, 
 COUNT(MR_number) as LLL
FROM  od_ar_demographics INNER JOIN
                         OD_IP1 ON od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_NUMBER = OD_IP1.IP0NUMBER WHERE  IP1admit_date >(getdate()- 180 ) GROUP BY MR_number
HAVING ( COUNT(MR_number) > 3 ))
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: This query isnt working. I am getting the error. Msg 170, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Line 6: Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: You are missing a closing parenthesis, at least.

Comment: @ypercube and an alias in one of the subqueries

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need alias for your subquery

```
SELECT od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_ARPTYPE, 
       od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_NAME, 
       od_ar_demographics.MR_NUMBER, 
       OD_IP1.IP1ADMIT_DATE, 
       OD_IP1.IP1DISC_DATE, 
       od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_TYPE
FROM  od_ar_demographics 
INNER JOIN OD_IP1 
    ON od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_NUMBER = OD_IP1.IP0NUMBER
WHERE Mr_number IN (SELECT MR_number 
                    FROM (  
                            SELECT MR_number, COUNT(MR_number) as LLL
                            FROM  od_ar_demographics 
                            INNER JOIN OD_IP1 
                            ON od_ar_demographics.PATIENT_NUMBER = OD_IP1.IP0NUMBER 
                            WHERE  IP1admit_date > getdate()- 180
                            GROUP BY MR_number
                            HAVING COUNT(MR_number) > 3 
                          ) A
                    )
```